# Schauder estimates for higher order linear elliptic operator on manifold

Tags: elliptic-pde, dg.differential-geometry

Hi!

Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth compact riemannian manifold without boundary. Let $L$ be a linear elliptic operator on $M$ of order $2k$ with smooth coefficients. Suppose i have $u\in W^{2k,2}(M)$ and $f\in C^{0,\alpha}(M)$ such that
$$L(u)=f$$
Do i have Schauder estimates of type

$$\left\|u\right\|_{C^{2k,\alpha}\left(M\right)}\leq C\left(L\right)\left\|f\right\|_{C^{0,\alpha}\left( M \right)}$$

I can assume also that $L$ (it would be better for $L$ of general type) is self adjoint and $u$ is $L^2$-orthogonal to $\ker\left(L \right)$.

If yes is there a reference for this kind of result?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Dear Italo I have tried to edit your question, it is ok for you?

Comment: Perfect! What was the problem?

Comment: When MathJax seems having problems, the basic solution is to enclose between backtips any TeX code containing underscores or asterisks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is true with some caveats. Under your assumptions we have the following results.

**1.** If $u\in W^{2k,2}(M)$ and $Lu\in C^{j,\alpha}(M)$, then $u\in C^{2k+j,\alpha}(M)$.

**2.**  There exists $C>0$ depending only on $M$, $L$, $j$, and $\alpha$ such that, for any  $u\in C^{2k+j,\alpha}(M)$ we have

$$\Vert u\Vert_{C^{2k+j,\alpha}}  \leq C\Bigl(\; \Vert Lu\Vert_{C^{j,\alpha}}+ \Vert u\Vert\_{C^{0,\alpha}}\;\Bigr) $$

**3.** There exists $C>0$ depending only on $M$, $L$, $j$, and $\alpha$ such that, for any  $u\in C^{2k+j,\alpha}(M)\cap (\ker L)^\perp $  (the $\perp$ refers to the $L^2$-inner product)   we have

$$\Vert u\Vert_{C^{2k+j,\alpha}}  \leq C \Vert Lu\Vert_{C^{j,\alpha}} $$

For proofs and more details see Chapter 10 of [these notes](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf) and the references therein.

Comment: Thank you very much Liviu! I'm reading your notes, once i work out the details i'll accept the answer! If i need, can i ask you some details?

Comment: Sure, you can ask me any questions.

Comment: Dear Liviu i have some questions:
1) how do you get the local $C^{2k,\alpha}$-regularity of $u$ if you only know that $u\in W^{2k,2}(M)$? 
I had this idea but it brought me nowhere: i can't use the elliptic estimates (thm 10.3.1 part b) of your notes as they are because you assume the $C^{k+j}$-regularity for $u$ so i mollify $u$ with a smoothing kernel $\rho_{\frac{1}{n}}$ obtaining a sequence of smooth functions $u_n=u\star \rho_{\frac{1}{n}}$  and i use cutoffs to come to the euclidean case. 

Comment: So i get elliptic estimates of type 
`  $$\left\|u_n\right\|_{C^{2k,\alpha}(M)}\leq C(L,M,g)\left(\left\|L(u_n)\right\|_{C^{0,\alpha}(M)} +\left\|u_n \right\|_{C^{0,\alpha}(M)} \right)$$  `
but now i can't get the $C^{0,\alpha}(M)$-convergence for $u_n$. 

Comment: 2) i've no idea on how to get the last inequality, for the $L^{p}$ case i have the generalized poincare inequality, but for the $C^{2k,\alpha}(M)$ i don't know how to go on. Thank you in advance! 

Comment: The  comment space is not enough for my answer. Write directly to my e-mail address nicolaescu.1 at nd.edu and I will reply to your e-mail address.

Comment: Dear Liviu, I tried to look up in your notes the inequality you wrote in item 3. The closest thing is Lemma 10.4.9 but it speaks about $L^1$ norms. Do you really mean $C^{k, \alpha}$ norms in your post above?

Comment: Dear David,  follow the proof in Lemma 10.4.9 where you replace the $L^{k,2}$-norms with the $C^{k,\alpha}$-norms and the $L^2$ estimates with  Holder estimates. Observe that $C^\alpha$ convergence implies $L^2$-convergence.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably more of a comment: Section 3.2 in [Lunardi's book](http://books.google.hu/books?id=mWojiHzg9bEC&printsec=frontcover) contains a broad overview on higher order parabolic problems with lots of references, including the most important Hölder estimates.

On manifolds, you should be able to extend these results using a finite number of coordinate charts (by compactness) as in [these notes](http://www.math.utsc.utoronto.ca/gpde/notes/schmfld.pdf). But, this is not a reference...